# Collatz Conjecture C++

Tags: c++

I created this function (see below), that works perfectly; however, I was tasked in changing the function to take a parameter that does the same thing just for the function I passed into it.

```
int collatz(){
int temp, num;
//num = 0;
cout << "pick a number to turn into one:";
cin >> num;
temp = 0;

while(num != 1){
    if(num%2 == 0){
    num = num/2;
    temp++;
    }
    else if(num&2 != 0){
        num = (3*num) + 1;
        temp++;
    }

}
cout << num << "number of times run: " << temp;
return 0;}
```

I came up with this; however, it gives me an error:

```
error C3861: 'collatztwo': identifier not found warning C4554: '&' : 
check operator precedence for possible error; 
use parentheses to clarify precedence
```

---

```
int collatztwo(int a){
int temp, num;
//num = a;

temp = 0;

while(a != 1){
    if(a%2 == 0){
    a = a/2;
    temp++;
    }
    else if(a&2 != 0){
        a = (3*a) + 1;
        temp++;
    }

}
cout <<  "looped: " << temp;
return 0;}
```

Comment: Without looking at the rest of your code, note that in `a&2 != 0` the `!=` operator has higher precedence than `&` (unfortunately). So put parentheses around the `a&2`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence (If you are testing if `a` is odd you want `(a&1)`)

Comment: It just gives me a build error, when I comment it out it works, but when its there it doesn't. I just don't understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Peter Can you paste this error here?

Comment: The function itself [compiles fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0fb153a66d2822d).

Comment: The higher precedence wasn't the issue, the error is

Comment: @Peter We need an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) and then this will most likely be solved in minutes.

Comment: **What Error** ? My build-log-clairvoyance is on the fritz today.

Comment: : error C3861: 'collatztwo': identifier not found
 warning C4554: '&' : check operator precedence for possible error; use parentheses to clarify precedence

Comment: @Matt I fixed the precedence errors, but I still get the error. Also the previous function that works doesn't have the problem and its identical

Comment: @Peter What's the main question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the errors OP listed in his comment:

```
error C3861: 'collatztwo': identifier not found
```

When you made your new function, did you include a [prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) for it before the call site? You have to declare `int collatztwo(int a);` at the top of your source file, or move the function definition before where you use it.

```
warning C4554: '&' : check operator precedence for possible error; use parentheses to clarify precedence
```

As already mentioned in the comments, you need to include a pair of parentheses around `a&2` or it will do the wrong thing. `else if ((a&2) != 0){`